# My script is not creating new row after last filled row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

Accidently something is changed and now my script is over writing rows instead of create new row after last filled row.

**So When I run script first time it fill data in 4 rows , and next time when I run then it should add data from 5th row but instead of that script is erasing old 4 row data and put new data there.**

Code :

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
         {

             Row newrow = sheet.createRow(rowcount+1);
             Cell cell = newrow.createCell(cellcount);

                            // newrow = sheet.getRow(rowcount);

             if(!data[i].equals("") || data[i].equals(null))
             {

                 if (cell == null && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                 {
                 row = sheet.createRow(rowcount);
                 cell.setCellValue(data[i]);
                 rowcount++;
             }

         }
             }

        }catch(Exception E)
        {
            E.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I am using Selenium Webdriver, POI to write data in excel. All data storing in array properly but not writing in new row.

When I debug , it returns to main for loop from `if (cell == null && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)` , In actual it should create new row after last filled row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How I understood the problem

I don't know if I understood your question correctly.

#### Add data to last row

So what you want to do is adding data from an array to an Excel sheet. But you want the data to be added to a new line at the end of the Excel sheet?

If so, you should maybe have a look at the method [`sheet.getLastRowNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getLastRowNum()).

#### Only add valid data

You also try to validate your data.

In your code, the data is only added to the cell if it is a non empty string or a null value. I don't know if that is what you wanted to do? Maybe it's a typo and you forgot a `!` in front of the `data[i].equals(null)`?

#### Null check of a fresh cell

First, you create a new cell and then you check if it is null. Why? A newly created cell should not be null.
I think, you rather wanted to make sure that the cell is not null (`cell != null`) but as I said that should not be the case. So this null check is redundant.

You could need that null check if you had used the method [`row.getCell(int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int)) because here the returned cell could be null.

Also the type check is not necessary because newly created cells are every time of type `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.

(Documentation: [`row.createCell(int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell(int)))

---

## Maybe a solution

I hope my code helps you! Feel free to ask.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (data[i] == null || data[i].equals("")) {
        continue; // Skip if data is unusable
    }

    final Row newRow = sheet.createRow(++rowCount); // Row indices are 0-based!
    final Cell cell = newRow.createCell(aColumnNumber); // Also column indices are 0-based!

    cell.setCellValue(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help , Actually when I run script first time , It fills data in 5 rows in my excel , then I change xpath and run again it gets new 5 data but not it should fill data from 6th row and instead of that it is deleting old 5 data and putting new data there. I would need solution for this.

Comment: Hey thanks , it is solved by  rowcount= sheet.getLastRowNum();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your condition state if.

> if (cell == null && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)

If your object cell == null, so you can't use a function of this object because ... your object is null.

Even if your cell is empty or whatever, it wouldn't be null. I don't really know what you want to check in the first part of your expression, but i'm pretty sure it's not : Check that this object is null.

In your instance, if your object is null, it wouldn't have any type. His variable (cell.type) would be null.

The if state will never be true.

Comment: Thanks for help , Actually when I run script it fill data in first 4 row of excel , now I want like when second time I run script , it should fill data from 5th row. But it again filling data from 1st row and over writing old data.